# Abstract Azure TableServiceEntity

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I want to abstract the implementation of my Azure TableServiceEntities so that I have one entity, that will take an object, of any type, use the properties of that object as the properties in the TableServiceEntity.

so my base object would be like

```
public class SomeObject
{
    [EntityAttribute(PartitionKey=true)]
    public string OneProperty {get; set:}
    [EntityAttribute(RowKey=true)]
    public string TwoProperty {get; set;}

    public string SomeOtherProperty {get;set;}
}

public class SomeEntity<T> : TableServiceEntity
{
    public SomeEntity(T obj)
    {           
        foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
        {
            object[] attributes = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (DataObjectAttributes), false);
            foreach (var attribute in attributes)
            {
                DataObjectAttributes doa = (DataObjectAttributes) attribute;
                if (doa.PartitionKey)
                    PartitionKey = propertyInfo.Name;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I could access the entity in the context like this

```
        var objects =
            (from entity in context.CreateQuery<SomeEntity>("SomeEntities") select entity);
        var entityList = objects.ToList();
        foreach (var obj in entityList)
        {
            var someObject = new SomeObject();
            SomeObject.OneProperty = obj.OneProperty;
            SomeObject.TwoProperty = obj.TwoProperty;
        }
```

This doesn't seem like it should be that difficult, but I have a feeling I have been looking at too many possible solutions and have just managed to confuse myself.

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

[Take a look at Lokad Cloud O/C mapper](http://lokadcloud.codeplex.com/) I think the source code imitates what you're attempting, but has insightful rationale about its different approach to Azure table storage.

http://lokadcloud.codeplex.com/

Comment: I have already looked at Lokad, but it looks like they use custom serialization to achieve what I want to do when setting up the entity.

Answer (score 0):

I have written an alternate Azure table storage client in F#, Lucifure Stash, which supports many abstractions including persisting a dictionary object. Lucifure Stash also supports large data columns > 64K, arrays & lists, enumerations, out of the box serialization, user defined morphing, public and private properties and fields and more.
It is available free for personal use at http://www.lucifure.com  or via NuGet.com.

What you are attempting to achieve, a single generic class for any entity, can be implemented in Lucifure Stash by using the [StashPool] attribute on a dictionary type.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a blog post about the table storage context, entities by specifying the entity type. Maybe it can help you http://wblo.gs/a2G

Answer (score 0):

It seems you still want to use concrete types. Thus, the SomeEntity is a bit redundant. Actually, TableServiceEntity is already an abstract class. You can derive SomeObject from TableServiceEntity. From my experience, this won’t introduce any issues to your scenario.

In addition, even with your custom SomeEntity, it is failed to remove the dependence on the concrete SomeObject class in your last piece of code anyway.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.